# Unity script fails when I build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't have much experience in game development but I wanted to experiment with an AI so I decided to make my own version of the Snake game to teach an AI to play; After a couple of problems I did it, I attached script eh reference images

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;


public static class MathUtilities
{
    public static void Random(this ref Vector3 myVector, Vector3 min, Vector3 max)
    {
        myVector = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(UnityEngine.Random.Range(min.x, max.x)), Mathf.RoundToInt(UnityEngine.Random.Range(min.y, max.y)), Mathf.RoundToInt(UnityEngine.Random.Range(min.z, max.z)));
    }
}

public class head : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum Direction
    {
        up,
        down,
        left,
        right
    }

    Direction direction;

    public List<Transform> tail = new List<Transform>();
    public List<GameObject> foodObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    public float frameRate = 0.2f;
    public float speed = 1f;
    public float score = 0;
    public GameObject TailPrefab;
    public GameObject FoodPrefab;
    public GameObject TailSection;
    public GameObject FoodSection;
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText; // Variable para almacenar la referencia al componente Text
    private Vector3 minVector = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    private Vector3 maxVector = new Vector3(19,-19,0);
    private Vector3 RanVector;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        scoreText = GameObject.Find("ScoreText").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        InvokeRepeating("Move", frameRate, frameRate);
    }

    void Move()
    {
        lastPos = transform.position;
        
        Vector3 nextPos = Vector3.zero;
        nextPos = Vector3.right;
        
        if (direction == Direction.up)
        {
            nextPos = Vector3.up;
        }
        else if (direction == Direction.down)
        {
            nextPos = Vector3.down;
        }
        else if (direction == Direction.left)
        {
            nextPos = Vector3.left;
        }
        else if (direction == Direction.right)
        {
            nextPos = Vector3.right;
        }
        nextPos *= speed;

        transform.position += nextPos;

        MoveTail();
    }

    Vector3 lastPos;

    void MoveTail()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tail.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 temp = tail[i].position;
            tail[i].position = lastPos;
            lastPos = temp;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && direction != Direction.down)
        {
            direction = Direction.up;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && direction != Direction.up)
        {
            direction = Direction.down;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && direction != Direction.right)
        {
            direction = Direction.left;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && direction != Direction.left)
        {
            direction = Direction.right;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if(col.CompareTag("Block"))
        {
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
            print("Game Over");
        }
        else if(col.CompareTag("Food"))
        {
            score ++;
            MathUtilities.Random(ref RanVector, minVector, maxVector);
            
            tail.Add(Instantiate(TailPrefab, tail[tail.Count - 1].position, Quaternion.identity, TailSection.transform).transform);



            foreach (GameObject food in foodObjects)
            {
                if (food.transform.position.x == transform.position.x && food.transform.position.y == transform.position.y)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Objeto de comida encontrado y destruido");
                    Destroy(food);
                    // Eliminar el objeto de comida de la lista
                    foodObjects.Remove(food);

                    break;
                }
            }

            GameObject foodObject = Instantiate(FoodPrefab, RanVector, Quaternion.identity, FoodSection.transform);
            foodObject.name = "food"; // Establecer un nombre personalizado para el objeto instanciado

            
            // Agregar el objeto de comida a la lista de comidas
            foodObjects.Add(foodObject);
        
        }
    }



}
```

[unity result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obD9Y.png)

I set the rigidbody, collider, food, score and everything works, I decided to do the build before implementing a TCP server and the necessary settings to connect it to an AI made with python but, now when I run the game, once I get the first one 'sphere' or as it is called in the game, the food, a new food is not generated in a random location (which when I run it from the unity editor does happen and the whole game works perfectly) the truth is not even I'm clear why it's failing

I reviewed all the code from top to bottom and searched multiple forums but I can't find why this happens, I saw problems with access paths somewhere but I don't use access paths.

Comment: What's RanVector? Did you debug it? Also, try replacing this: `public static void Random(this ref Vector3 myVector` with this: `public static void Random(out Vector3 myVector` and this `MathUtilities.Random(ref RanVector` with this `MathUtilities.Random(out RanVector`.

Comment: Is MathUtilities class in separate cs file? Unlikely to be the reason but generally it is good for MonoBehaviours to be the only class in the file.

Comment: In general using `ref` here is a bit confusing .. why not simply e.g. `public static Vector3 Range(Vector3 min, Vector3 max) => new Vector3(Mathf.Lerp(min.x, max.x, Random.value), Mathf.Lerp(min.y, max.y, Random.value), Mathf.Lerp(min.z, max.z, Random.value));`

Comment: Have you tried to add more logs and check the player log file of your built application for any errors / strange behavior?